# circle divs in holder with overflow:hidden scroll vertically and horizontally scroll - mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseevent

I'm trying to make circle divs in holder div. with `overflow:hidden;`. I am experiencing some problems with the mousemove event. Here is my example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pAu8Q/510/) and here is my goal: [ello.co](http://ello.co). I also searched some questions about mousemove but I couldn't find vertically and horizontally together.
html:

```
<div id="holder"><ul id="scroll">
<li><div class="si"></div></li>
<li><div class="si"></div></li><ul>
<li><div class="si"></div></li><ul>  
</ul>
</ul></div>
```

css:

```
#holder {
    background: pink;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#scroll{
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#scroll li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.si{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:black;
  float:left;
  border-radius:150px;
  margin:10px;
}
.si:hover{
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
  margin:2px;
}
```

javascript:

```
var sum = 0;
$("#scroll li").each(function() {
    sum += $(this).width() + parseInt($(this).css('paddingLeft')) + parseInt($(this).css('paddingRight'))
});
$("#scroll").css('width', sum);

$("#holder").mousemove(function(e) {
    x = -(((e.pageX - $('#scroll').position().left) / $("#holder").width()) * ($("#scroll").width() + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingLeft')) + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingRight')) - $("#holder").width()));

    $("#scroll").css({
        'marginLeft': x + 'px'
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/www139/540c238y/

Comment: no, i want exactly like ello.co thank you for comment

Comment: What are your problems with 'mousemove'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have it move vertically as well, you can use the same code as for x and adapt it:

http://jsfiddle.net/pAu8Q/511/

```
y = -(((e.pageY - $('#scroll').position().left) / $("#holder").width()) * ($("#scroll").width() + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingTop')) + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingBottom')) - $("#holder").width()));

$("#scroll").css({
    'marginTop': y + 'px'
});
```

Comment: yes, exactly! thank you for help. i am really new at coding. also how can i do it with more lines, more circles. when i add another div. it's going side by side.

Comment: If you have a new question, you might want to post a new question 

Comment: you can do multiply lines like this (http://jsfiddle.net/pAu8Q/513/) but then I think the scroll won't be as you'd like anymore. I think that would need more look at it in a new Question, or maybe you can do it yourself 